# ssh vagrant Not working inside Virtual box VM

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, virtualbox, virtual-machine, vagrant

I have Ubuntu VM in Virtual Box :

```
# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
Release:        14.04
Codename:       trusty
```

ssh vagrant is Not working inside above Ubuntu VM :

```
root@ubuntu-study-docker:~# vagrant init ubuntu-14.04
`Vagrantfile` already exists in this directory. Remove it before
running `vagrant init`.
root@ubuntu-study-docker:~# vagrant up --provider=virtualbox
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
root@ubuntu-study-docker:~# vagrant ssh
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
```

My Vagrantfile :

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
config.vm.box = "ubuntu-14.04"
end
```

Comment: There is no such box as just `ubuntu-14.04`. No one knows what box you use. Then what does your Ubuntu VM you mention in paragraph have to do with the rest of the question? Is it a host? A guest? If so, what's the relation to Vagrant box? It's quite a good example of how not to ask a question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try to run the vagrant box in the host machine and access it from your ubuntu virtual machine via network configuration.

You should not use VMs in VMs; is a problem of allowing virtualization at the bios level: https://teamtreehouse.com/community/vagrant-ssh-sshexchangeidentification-read-connection-reset-by-peer and apparently that cannot be done in VMs. I tried (http://hackaholic.info/enable-hardware-virtualization-vt-x-amd-v-for-virtualbox/) even changing the paravirtualization interface does not work.